# Access all controls from any program installed in my computer and mack changes to them using c#?

Tags: c#

I'm Accessing some program using

```
Process proc = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(n => n.MainWindowTitle == "ProgremTiitle");
```

And i would like to fill data in a dropdown list , and i wanna fill out some textBox but i cannot access this controls  any help ?

Comment: See [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx)